# Objective-C – Correct procedure to set a ViewController to be the delegate for another Class

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uiviewcontroller

Say I have 1 View Controller and one Model class; `ViewController` and `Model`

In `Model` I have a method that looks like this:

```
[object setDelegate:self]
```

Instead I want ViewController to act as the delegate. How and where would I do this?

Should I `alloc` and `init` my ViewController in my `- init` method of the Model like:

```
ViewController *newVc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self setVc:newVc]; // retains newVc
[newVc release];
```

And then do:

```
[object setDelegate:[self vc]];
```

Please throw some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but if *object* is you model you may have an issue with circular references, you have you model retaining the the viewController and your viewController retaining your model, neither is going to get there dealloc method called to release the other. I would look at using notifications your view controller can have a direct connection to you model but your model can broadcast changes to anybody who cares, you view controller can then observer an notification from you model. I usually like to think that my model code should be able to function with any interface, even as a command line program.

Comment: Object in this case is actually an instance of `ASIHTTPRequest` as such `ASIHTTPRequest *object = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];`

Comment: OK, I would tend to think of your model as being a suitable delegate of you ASIHTTPRequest, or maybe event creating a separate class to act as a delegate that is a property of your model class. It hard to say without seeing our complete project. ViewController are just classes that act as go-betweens of the function of you app (model) and how that function is presented to the user. I have only briefly look at ASIHTTPRequest so maybe it is self contained model class in itself in which case making your view controller a delegate of it is a reasonable solution.